# Can a formula return the name of a page in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint

I have a large customer list in SharePoint 2013 and I want to create individual pages for each customer.  In those pages I want to show a view of the main list with only that customers data.  I am trying to find a way to do a formula that reads the name of the page so I can tell the view to only display info where the column customer equals the name of the page.  Does anyone know if it is possible to write a formula that will return the name of the page?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a good idea because generally you want one customer not to see all other customers. If you do like you suggest each customer will still has access to all others customer's information. I think the best approach is to set permissions for each individual customer's item. Then when putting list view web part customer will see only his item because security trimming will do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are much better and easier solution. Just create new List View and set filter option on your customer field to current user, like [here](http://go.limeleap.com/community/bid/297846/Custom-List-View-Based-on-Current-User-Using-SharePoint-Designer).

Comment: I am trying to make a dynamic solution though.  I don't want to have to create different view for every single customer.  The data is used internally by management and I'm trying to connect a filter to the list but I don't see the "connect" option in the filter web part and it says my list is unsupported when I'm editing the filter.  Any idea what the requirements are for filters?